# Shell script: filter list of .pdf files, to exclude those with a .tex source file

Tags: shell-script, git

I have a linebreak-separated list of file paths, all to pdf files.  I would like to filter out all those which have a corresponding `*.tex` file in the same directory (and so can be presumed auto-generated).

For instance, if the list includes `foo.tex`, `foo.pdf`, `bar.pdf`, I would like the script to output just `bar.pdf`.  If I have `foo/foo.tex` and `bar/foo.pdf`, I would like the script to output `bar/foo.pdf`.

(The use-case is as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/382201/gitignoring-pdf-file-only-when-a-tex-source-is-present): I have a git repository containing both tex files and externally produced pdfs.  The auto-generated pdfs should not be tracked by git, but others should be.  The solution I have in mind is to put `*.pdf` in the `.gitignore`, but add a git post-commit hook which warns me when there are untracked pdfs other than those generated from `.tex` files. I am getting the list of untracked pdfs with `git status --ignored *.pdf`, but am not sure how to cleanly implement this next step.)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a regular loop with [`[ -e`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) and [`${xxx%.pdf}`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to check for and construct the filenames. This reads the paths on standard input, one per line:

```
while read path
do
    [ -e "${path%.pdf}.tex" ] || echo "$path"
done
```

`"${path%.pdf}"` [expands to](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) `$path` with ".pdf" stripped off the end, and then we can put the ".tex" on the end directly. If it `-e`xists then we do nothing, and otherwise (`||`) it prints out the path to the PDF. You could put more complicated logic and behaviour in there if you wanted.

The usual caveats about the value of `IFS` and filenames containing newlines, etc, apply, but assuming that you have nothing unusual going on that all works straightforwardly.